# What is the NGXS equivalent of NGRX's provideMockStore

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, ngxs

I'm trying to Unit test a class, that uses a NGXS store(I'm not trying to unit test the store itself).

In NGRX, you have a `provideMockStore`([here](https://v10.ngrx.io/api/store/testing/provideMockStore)). What would be the equivalent with NGXS?

For illustration, here is my class to be tested:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const currentToken = this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.accounts.accessToken);

    if (currentToken) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}` },
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

And here how I'm trying to test it:

```
describe('Token interceptor', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    return MockBuilder(AuthTokenInterceptor, AppModule)
      .exclude(NG_MOCKS_INTERCEPTORS)
      .keep(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS)
      .replace(HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule);
  });

  it('adds the token when authenticated', () => {
    //Arrange
    const fixture = MockRender('');
    const client: HttpClient = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(HttpClient);
    const httpMock: HttpTestingController = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    const store: Store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
    const fakeToken = 'Wunderbar';
    store.reset({ accounts: { accessToken: fakeToken } });

    //Act
    client.get('/target').subscribe();

    //Assert
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/target');
    req.flush('');
    httpMock.verify();

    expect(req.request.headers.get('Authorization')).toEqual(`Bearer ${fakeToken}`);
  });    
  
});
```

But it always fails, even I've tried to "reset" the store with the token, when I console.log the access token in the interceptor, I get undefined. So how do I properly set the current state to be used in this unit test?

(ps, this is only an example but I've the same question for a lot of different tests)